# how to extract main topic and sub topic words(bold word) from pdf in python?

Tags: database, data-science, data-mining, text-mining

Is there any way to extract bold word from pdf? Any way to extract only main topic words and sub topic words? I have used many python library like PyPDF2, Text-tact and re many more. I have read the pdf file one and print page by page. But i can not print full pdf together and also not extract just high weight words means bold words means main and sub topic words.

Comment: You can use this online tool: http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/